My emmet and user snippet is not working and also same problem in CSS and in also python it can not recommand me anything
These are the photo of seting.json and even I also watch so may videos of you tube and I apply all these tricks that they but it didn't work.
I uninstall the vs and again install but not working please help me how i resolve this problem I also saw so many docs but not working the problem is same not working at all..


